# Question on Cancellation Property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Let m, n, and p be integers. If m*n=m*p and m is not equal to 0 then n=p.
I'm supposed to find and prove which n the set Zn satisfies this property. 
I know how to actually prove the property but not what exact conditions for n make it true. I assumed n could be any integer, which is why I'm slightly confused about the question. Any help on how to start this off would be good. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works if and only if $n$ is prime, in which case $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field and cancellation property holds.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be just any $n$. For example, suppose $n=6$.  Then $3\cdot 2 = 3\cdot 4 = 0$ (mod $6$) and yet $2 \not = 4$

Comment: I'm still not getting why n would have to be prime, couldn't you easily have an example where neither n and p are prime? Unless I'm misunderstanding the property.

Comment: @JanoyCresva An example with *some* $m,n,p$, yes, but it has to hold for *all*. And by the way, I am not saying in my answer that it has to be prime ... just pointing out it cannot be any integer (but yes, analyzing this example, and thinking how one can avoid this kind of situation, one's thoughts quickly turn to primes ...)

Comment: Ok I think I got it now. If it didn't have to hold for all like you said, n would not necessarily have to be a prime, right?

Comment: @JanoyCresva Well, that's for you to make hard, i.e. prove.